# react-router load on-demand issue

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, code-splitting

I use `Dynamic Routing` to make code split

```
const CourseRoute = {
  path: 'course/:courseId',
  getComponents(nextState, callback) {
    require.ensure([], function (require) {
      callback(null, require('./components/Course'))
    })
  }
}
```

But the problem is, when the network is slow enough, it looks like the app stuck for seconds before transition to next page. Because it has to wait until the downloading of next page file is finished.

Can I add a progress bar during the transition, if so, how to implement it?

Is there a webpack API or React-Router API?